# Upgrade existing website to OAuth2 authorization server

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

We have an existing website "A" with registered users that runs independently (users are stored in database with username and password-hash). Users log in and get a cookie set when authorized.

A 2nd team want's to build another website "B" allowing our existing users access to their site. Site "B" will have its independent profile, preferences and rights management, so the scope is just authentication and minimal authorization (is user or admin).

I tried to understand [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) but quickly got lost. Our exiting website "A" would be the "Authorization server" while the new website "B" would be the "Resource Owner".

What I need is a list of calls that need to be implemented by the Authorization Server "A" in order to enable the team building "B" to use standard out-of-the-box components that facilitate OAuth2 authentication.

Has anyone compiled a list of API calls needed for an authorization service?

A minimal example implementation would be great!

Comment: How does the website "A" store membership information? Is it using asp.net identity behind the scene? Building an authorization server to support Oauth 2.0 can be time consuming.

Comment: @TejSoft website "A" is only using asp.net identity for the front end (we used most of the scaffolding razor pages). For the actual user storage, profiles and password hash checking, we removed all entity framework stuff and replaced it with our legacy code so we don't have to rewrite libs or migrate anything.

Comment: If you are using Asp.Net identity for website "A", then you can use IdentityServer3 (`https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3`) (not sure about IdentityServer4) to connect to the membership database directly. IdSvr3 will then be the identity server for other websites "B", "C", "D" ...etc where the same users can login to the other websites using the same credentials.

Comment: @TejSoft you could post your IdentityServer3 comment as an answer. It was far from trivial but we now have a working solution using IdentityServer3. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Never thought it could be so complicated!

Comment: glad to know that my comment took you in a direction that solved the problem. Why don't you write an answer yourself, with a diagram showing how you solved it? It will greatly help many others who might land on this question looking for solutions.